# How to disable Flash right-click context menu in MS Edge browser

Tags: flash, contextmenu, microsoft-edge, right-click

I'm trying to disable Flash context menu from appearing.
I managed to do it in chrome/firefox/explorer by capturing the mouseup/mousedown/contextmenu events and preventing their propagation.

This doesn't work for the Edge browser.
Any ideas?